# powershell Store files in an array?

Tags: powershell

Not sure if this is the best option or if its even possible so open to suggestions of other ways to achieve my goal. I did try searching but didn't find anything.

I currently have a script that pulls data for several dozen sites and generates an email for each site. My Team lead has asked me to figure out a way to instead generate 1 email with an attachment for each site. I can export a file for each site then should be able to select those files to send with the email. however I'm curious if I can put these generated files in an array instead of writing them to disk then send them with the email.

Any suggestions would be appreciated (even if its to tell me I'm out to lunch).

Comment: how big are these files?

Comment: the generated emails are about 7 meg combined

Comment: You can put the content of the file in a byte array and create a matrix with one array per file. That is, assuming the content is binary.